# Android - webview show different behaviour when excute javascript code

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am working in project read user input via voice and write in web site , I read all site input id by jsoup

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    new ParseURl().execute(new String[]{url});
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl(passed_site);
```

method to read all input ids it work just fine

```
private class ParseURl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Elements inputs = doc.select("input[type=text]");
                for (Element ele : inputs) {
                    listID.add(ele.attr("id"));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


       }


                if(listID.size()>0){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result){
                readMyVoice();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(WebPage.this , "your site dont have input to fill" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

if site contain input it start write to it by take user input

```
 private void readMyVoice() {
        Intent voicerecogize = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        voicerecogize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
        voicerecogize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        voicerecogize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ar-SA");
        startActivityForResult(voicerecogize, RESULT_SPEECH);
    }



 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_SPEECH && requestCode == RESULT_OK) ;
        {
            ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            if (results.size() > 0 ) {

                StartFillSiteForm(listID.get(count),results.get(0));
                count++;
                if(listID.size() == count){
                    return;
                }else{
                    readMyVoice();
                }
            }

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

here is the issue , all work fine when this method try write user input to web site it open new page empty one  like screen shot below , it should write this in website input

```
private void StartFillSiteForm(String id , String value){

        webView.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById('"+id+"').value='" + value + "';");

    }
```

tested site google

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should enable javascript in Android Activity

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
}
```

Comment: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher. Learn More about it on: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html